# Memory layout of JavaScript objects in V8

Tags: c, node.js, v8

I'm looking to writing some C bindings to V8, and so I'll need to figure out the memory layout of the various primitive JavaScript types. Is there any documentation on these details anywhere?

Comment: Are you asking about objects or primitive values now?

Comment: Primitives + Object, technically speaking.

Comment: Are you asking for a nodejs-c binding or for developing directly against v8?   There is documentation for both both in different places -- and you DON'T want to access the memory directly in either case, but use the API

Comment: If a C binding exists, that would save me a lot of time, but I couldn't find one. I want to do things like "take a String from JavaScript and do work on it in C", and was assuming I would have to write a C++ V8 wrapper that exposes C functions, since V8 is in C++.

Comment: (The eventual intention is to use this with Node)

Comment: The Node.js manual have some information -- see this for additional information -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051070/node-js-c-addon-threading/22946062

Comment: @soren, that's all C++. I need C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to know data types layout to write C bindings for V8. Object's are never really accessed directly when you work with V8 but through an API - only V8 implementation knows how they are laid out. For example getting a property `foo` from an object `o` looks like this in C++:

```cpp
v8::Handle<v8::Object> o;
v8::Handle<v8::Object> v =
  o->Get(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "foo"));
```

Now to wrap this into C you *only* need to know how to represent and pass around `v8::Handle<T>`, then you can write wrappers like:

```cpp
template<typename T> Handle<T> FromC(v8_handle_t h) { /* ... */ }
template<typename T> v8_handle_t ToC(Handle<T> h) { /* ... */ }

extern "C" v8_handle_t v8_object_get(v8_handle_t self, 
                                     v8_handle_t key) {
  return ToC(FromC<Object>(self)->Get(FromC<Value>(key)));
}
```

So what's inside `v8::Handle<T>`? In reality it's just a pointer to some slot which in turn contains an actual pointer to an underlying V8 object. This double indirection exists to enable V8 GC to precisely track which objects are in use in C++ code and to allow it moving this objects.

So theoretically you can define `v8_handle_t` as an opaque pointer and marshall it like this:

```cpp
typedef struct v8_object_pointer_t* v8_handle_t;  // Opaque pointer
static_assert(sizeof(v8_handle_t) == sizeof(Handle<Object>))
template<typename T> Handle<T> FromC(v8_handle_t h) {
  return *(Handle<T>*)&h;
}
template<typename T> v8_handle_t ToC(const Handle<T>& h) {
  return *(v8_handle_t*)&h;
}
```

A minor complication comes from managing the structure called `HandleScope` that manages `Handle`s. In C++ API it relies on RAII-pattern to manage some backing storage. The simplest way to deal with it probably is:

```cpp
typedef struct {
  void* a[3];
} v8_handle_scope_t;
static_assert(sizeof(v8_handle_scope_t) == sizeof(HandleScope))
void v8_handle_scope_enter(v8_handle_scope_t* scope) {
  new(scope) HandleScope; 
}
void v8_handle_scope_leave(v8_handle_scope_t* scope) {
  delete (HandleScope*)scope;
}
```

With carefully balanced usage in code that needs handle scopes:

```cpp
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  v8_handle_scope_t scope;
  v8_handle_scope_enter(&scope);
  // action
  v8_handle_scope_leave(&scope);
}
```

Comment: excellent, thank you a ton. For my use case, I'm mostly interested in just copying out the data immediately rather than worrying about keeping objects alive, specifically because I was worried about GC rooting and other things you mention.

Comment: @SteveKlabnik well, V8 api is explicitly designed this way to prevent any worries about rooting - that's why all objects are always rooted (unless you violate HandleScope nesting and pass around invalid handles)

Answer (score 1):

As your question is about how to write V8 C++ addons for Node.js you should just refer to the manual for [nodeJs which has a reasonably simple guide for writing addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html);

If you question is about how to make background threads then there are nodejs plugins which helps you with that, but [also read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051070/node-js-c-addon-threading/22946062) for how to write it directly.

You should never try to access the memory for V8 directly, as the memory and object may move --always use the APIs

Comment: My question is about how to write C extensions, not C++.

Comment: You will have to wrap your C in C++

Comment: Yes. In order to do that, I need to know things like the memory layout of the structs, hence the question.

Comment: The only way you can do what you need to do is to write C++ code which moves data to/from your C code into C++ and then call the Nodejs/V8 API from C++

Comment: Correct. Which is why I need to understand these details, so I know how to turn those C structures into the correct ones V8 uses.

Comment: You need to read the C++ code I have referenced -- `Number::New(42)` is how you create a int value=42 in the interface -- you cannot access the memory directly

Comment: Keep in mind also that the V8 API changes fairly frequently.  So even if you were somehow able to create C structs that mapped to the V8 internal goodies, they can change release-to-release.  I guess [node-ffi](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi) isn't going to help, but ... passing it along just in case.  There's also [nan](https://github.com/nodejs/nan) - tries to abstract away the shifting V8 API for node developers.

Comment: @PatrickMueller yeah, that was something I was thinking of too, such is the life of a bindings author.